# Is there a formula for the norm of an orthogonal projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition, svd

In all introductory linear algebra texts there is a discussion on orthogonal projection.

Let $u = w_1 + w_2$, where $w_1$ is the projection of $u$ along $v$ and $w_2$ is projection of orthogonal to $v$.

We know that $w_1 = \frac{u \cdot v}{v \cdot v} v $ and $||w_1|| = ||u||\, |\cos{\theta}|$ or simply $|u \cdot v|$ if $v$ is a unit vector.

In the textbook, there is no mention of $||w_2||$ and I wonder if there is a formula for it.

$|| w_2 || = || u  -  \frac{u \cdot v}{v \cdot v}v || \longrightarrow $ what?

Comment: First of all,
$$
\|w_1\| = \frac{|u\cdot v|}{|v\cdot v|} \|v\| = \frac{|u\cdot v|}{\| v \|^2}\| v\| = \frac{|u\cdot v|}{\|v\|}
$$
Then, use the abstract version of Pithagora's theorem: since $w_1$ and $w_2$ are perpendicular,
$$
\|u\|^2 = \|w_1\|^2 + \|w_2\|^2 \implies \|w_2\|= \sqrt{\|u\|^2-\|w_1\|^2}
$$
If you want you can substitute back $\|w_1\|$ from the first line, maybe this is what you are looking for?